# Is the fundamental weight basis (a.k.a Dynkin basis) an orthonormal basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

The simple root $\alpha_i$ basis is not an orthonormal basis, as can be seen from the Cartan matrix, [which encodes how much they aren't orthonormal](https://books.google.de/books?id=B_JQryjNYyAC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=simple%20roots%20dynkin%20basis&source=bl&ots=Xsw_aQ9Zoc&sig=s7_UpYIkjpfJUdkuzpSLuQoA1XE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIp9Xq8bzExwIVQr4UCh1y-QgZ#v=onepage&q=simple%20roots%20dynkin%20basis&f=false).

*For simplicity, let's assume a simply-laced Lie algebra where the simple simple roots are self-dual.*

In the Dynkin basis we write each weight with the components with respect to the fundamental weights $\Lambda_i$. These are defined by their property

$$ \Lambda_i(\alpha_j) = \delta_{ij} . $$

Does this mean that the Dynkin basis is an orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Look at $\mathfrak{sl}_3$. The simple roots are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ with
$$(\alpha_1,\alpha_1)=2\;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\;(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=-1.$$

Write $\Lambda_1=a\alpha_1+b\alpha_2$ and solve the system 
$$\begin{cases}(\Lambda_1,\alpha_1)=1\\(\Lambda_1,\alpha_2)=0\end{cases}$$
to get $\Lambda_1=\frac{2}{3}\alpha_1+\frac{1}{3}\alpha_2$ (similarly, $\Lambda_2=\frac{1}{3}\alpha_1+\frac{2}{3}\alpha_2$).

Now compute that $(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_1)=\frac{2}{3}$ and $(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thx a lot! The same calculation for $su(3)$ can be found here https://books.google.de/books?id=5u7jBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA505&lpg=PA505&dq=fundamental+weights+scalar+product&source=bl&ots=vwp3YwwXxF&sig=Fz-4CWsZzqKgc0alPha3k25plX4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBGoVChMIo56cjbXGxwIVwsAUCh2I8QkF#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20weights%20scalar%20product&f=false